# How to fix jittery movement (of a player which is a square)

Tags: java

Currently, I'm coding this 2D game in Java. I added this little player (a square) and added movements to it (move up, down, right, and left using WASD keys). The problem is, whenever I press the keys to move the player, the movement isn't smooth and it jitters. I want the movement to be smooth whenever I move the player around. I have looked and searched on Youtube for any solutions and searched on Stack Overflow too. I couldn't find any solution that fixed my problem so I decided to ask on here. If ANYONE knows how to get rid of the jittery movement of my player, please post the answer on here please.

Comment: Without example of code which demonstrates your issues, I would "guess", don't use `KeyListener`, use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead.  Instead of responding directly to the event, use a `Set` of some kind which holds which keys are currently active.  When press, you add a value to the `Set`, when released, your remove the value from the `Set`.  In your main loop, update the position of the object based on what's currently active in the `Set`

Comment: Right, thanks for taking your time to respond! And, this pretty much helped me. Thanks